# Share large datasets between a group

Tags: share, bigdata

Can please someone suggest an online services to share large files, over 100GB, amongst a group of people? 
Specifically, we are working on a machine learning project that requires constant access to the files but without the need to download them. For this project we will manipulate the files with python and R, I know that I can upload and share the code with Git but is there a service (like docker?) that you can store information and 'play' with it online?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Common practice - use Git for your code and S3 for data.

You can also check open source tool DVC - http://dataversioncontrol.com -
 which orchestrates Git modeling code with S3 or GCP storage. It was designed for ML scenarios. Python and R code both are supported by DVC.